# Finding the edge symmetry and face symmetry group of regular tetrahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, symmetric-groups

I am trying exercises of Ch-14 Introductory Combinatorics by Richard Brualdi .

The questions in which author asks to find Edge symmetry group and Face symmetry group of regular tetrahedron are really lengthy to work out. I did the case for finding symmetry group of regular tetrahedron and it had 24 elements. During the class discussion ( before giving the exercise) the instructor told us that the Symmetry group, edge symmetry group and face symmetry group are isomorphic.

> My question is, can someone tell  some way to prove that Edge symmetry group and face symmetry group is isomorphic to Symmetry group without actually finding the Edge symmetry group and face symmetry group ?

OR

> A less lengthy way to find Edge symmetry group and face symmetry group?

Comment: I'm guessing by "edge symmetry group" you mean the symmetry group interpreted as a set of permutations of the edges? (And similarly for face symmetry group.) The symmetry group itself is a set of rotations (3x3 matrices). You can define homomorphism from the symmetry group to the edge and face symmetry groups and argue they are isomorphisms. (Automatically onto, check the kernel is trivial; no nontrivial rotation permutes no things.)

Comment: @runway44 can you tell what are those homomorphisms?  Details are required. Outlines are clear to me also.

Comment: I mean, say you have a rotation. What does it do to edges? It permutes them. You know how to turn a rotation into a permutation, no? Literally just see which edge turns into which...